# FFMPEG -filter_complex is not generating desired output

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to 
    embed subtitle at the bottom of video and 
    add image/text watermark at the top right corner of video and 
    add text at the top and bottom and 
    add colored padding at top and bottom of video in the same command

This following is the command I can get somewhat working. This is adding padding at the bottom but not at the top. It is successfully embedding subtitles in the video though.
It is also disturbing some parts of the video, pushing them to the top and cropping the top of video (because of padding at the bottom I think) but some parts of the video are in place and are ok.

I tried to write the command and use filter complex in FFMPEG but i am not sure how to use them correctly. Can somebody guide how to fix this and use filter complex correctly as documentation is too complex

COMMAND

```
ffmpeg -y -i video-orignal.mp4 -i watermark.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=iw:ih+300:0:0:purple[padded]; [padded]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:5[watermarked]; [0:v][watermarked]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10,subtitles=subtitles-final.ass[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a video-final.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding and watermark overlay corrected. Text added at top and bottom.

```
ffmpeg -y -i video-orignal.mp4 -i watermark.jpg
  -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=iw:ih+300:0:150:purple[padded];
                   [padded][1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:155,
                              subtitles=subtitles-final.ass,
   drawtext=fontfile='/path/to/font':fontsize=50:fontcolor=white:text='Top Text':
            x=main_w/2:y=160,
   drawtext=fontfile='/path/to/font':fontsize=50:fontcolor=white:text='Bottom Text':
            x=main_w/2:y=main_h-th-160[out]"
  -map "[out]" -map 0:a video-final.mp4
```

Comment: can you please tell what is the meaning of [0:v] in filter_complex. rest make sense

Comment: so let say i want to add text at top and bottom so can you write command for that as well. thank you so much for helping me out

Comment: `[0:v]` tells ffmpeg that the first filter will be operating upon the first video stream of the first input.

Comment: thank you for your help. only last thing if i wanted to add audio into video as well. i have 3 audio files e.g from 1 to 10 sec audio1.mp3  and from 10 to 20 audio2.mp3 and so on

Comment: After adding the 3 files after the watermark, insert after `[out]` `;[2:a]atrim=0:10[2a];[3:a]atrim=0:10,adelay=10000|10000[3a];[4:a]atrim=0:10,adelay=20000|20000[4a];[0:a][2a][3a][4a]amix=4[aout]"` and map this output as well `-map "[aout]"`

Comment: Which output? If you make the changes, both the video and merged audio will be present.

Comment: @Mulvya can you please check command in my answer. it is not woking.

Comment: @Mulvy ffmpeg amix is not working

[AVFilterGraph @ 0x3032760] No such filter: 'amix‌​'

Comment: Your binary doesn't have amix, so you'll need one which does.

Comment: I have ffmpeg with avfilter

Comment: Also can u reply here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073912/ffmpeg-filter-complex-drawtext-with-style-like-bold-italic-and-underline#

Comment: i tried everything but no luck. here is the output of my compiled binary and also precompiled binary from https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

https://gist.github.com/mubbashar/8fbff377d5b889b1233401c8ca965c24

Comment: fixed it. there was some extra hidden character with amix filter. happened when i copied this command from stackoverflow :(

Answer (score 0):

**Due to characters limit of comment I am asking it here**

@Mulvya I am too looking for the same thing. here is the command I made

```
ffmpeg -y -i video-orignal.mp4 -i watermark.jpg -i audio1.mp3 -i audio2.mp3 -i audio3.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=iw:ih+300:0:150:purple[padded]; [padded][1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:155, subtitles=subtitles-final.ass, drawtext=fontfile='/path/to/font':fontsize=50:fontcolor=white:text='Top Text': x=main_w/2:y=160, drawtext=fontfile='/path/to/font':fontsize=50:fontcolor=white:text='Bottom Text': x=main_w/2:y=main_h-th-160 [out]; [2:a]atrim=0:10[2a]; [3:a]atrim=0:10,adelay=10000|10000[3a]; [4:a]atrim=0:10,adelay=20000|20000[4a]; [0:a][2a][3a][4a]amix=4 [aout]" -map "[out]" -map "[aout]" -map 0:a video-final.mp4
```

it is generating the video with text and watermark.jpg image but audio files are not adding into the output video. can you please look into the command and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Both the original audio and mixed audio is included into the output. Maybe your player ignores the mixed stream. Remove `-map 0:a`. Share the full console output in a new Q if it doesn't work